# Remove directive form HTML AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is possible to remove direcive `ng-cloak` from another directive?
I have directive like this:

```
       .directive('loading', loading);


function loading($http) {
    var loadingSniper = {
        link: link,
        restrict: "AE"
    };

    return loadingSniper;

    function link(scope, elm, attrs)
    {

        scope.$watch('isLoading', function(){
           //I NEED TO REMOVE NG-CLOAK FROM HERE
        });
    }

}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="splash" ng-cloak="">
            <h2>Loading</h2>
       </div>
        <div ng-cloak=""> 
</div>
```

I added comment from where I want to remove ng-cloak.... Any idea?

Comment: If you need to show/hide only, you can do <div ng-show="isLoading">... ng-cloak has special purposes on angularjs

Comment: but, if you need to show something antecipate, you can to use elm.removeAttr('ng-cloak')

Comment: Problem is `ng-cloak` is not under app module....

Comment: doesn't make sense...why is it there if it isn't within the app? Where is `ng-app`? Please show all relevant code

Comment: but, if doesn't under app module, your directive doesn't be compiled... if you need, use jQuery $('[ng-cloak]').removeAttr('ng-cloak');